# Can the Elytra become too expensive to repair?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Or does the XP cost of repairs remain the same no matter how many times it has been repaired?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elytra is the same as all other repairable items in that the XP cost will become more expensive with each repair.

From quick testing, I was able to repair it 5 times before I was unable to repair it any more.